# Routes vs RoutesConfig in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have been using @RouteConfig but it is now deprecated and I think @Routes will be replacing it, but don't have any info on how to use it. When I use it similar to @RouteConfig as follows:

```
{path: '/', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
```

it gives error and expects something like RouteMetadata[].

Can someone please guide me where to find examples of @Route and syntax for RouteMetadata.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8972

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
@Routes({path: '/', component: DashboardComponent})
```

While this doesn't:

```
@Routes({path: '/', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent})
```

The reason is that they removed the `name` as well as `data`. Hopefully they'll be back in later releases. Interestingly, the documentation at [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) is totally gone (atm) which means they might re-write the router one more time.

Comment: I think they are bad at naming things. Shouldn't it be called `Alpha` and not `Beta`. And yes the missing `name` property is causing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: They do things their way. They have alpha.1 to alpha.infinity and beta.1 to beta.infinity and then a RC.1 to ... well we'll get a production version at some point!

Comment: FYI.. in angular.io, they have already written that they are writing rc-router documents. :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you import all required references ? I guess your config is correct,something like

```
 @Routes([
      {path: '/', component: DashboardComponent},
      {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent}
    ])
```

Here is some [sample docs](https://playcode.org/routing-in-angular-2-rc-1/)